# Dúvida com consulta sql usando intervalor de tempo

Tags: sql-server

Tenho um Job no sql server que roda duas vezes ao dia, 06:00 e as 18:00, ele possui uma consulta sql onde eu pego a data do processo e comparo com a data do dia. Acontece que se tiver uma nova alteração após as 18:00, estas não vão ser atualizadas porque vai ser uma nova data após as 24:00 horas.
Como eu poderia compensar este tempo em horas na consulta, adicionando este resultado? Eu poderia altera o horário da job mais o cliente acha que não, que queria uma outra solução, eu não consigo ver uma solução.
O campo c.dtHrProcesso tem a data no formato : 2016-11-23 04:38:10.307

```html
Segue a consulta 
SELECT DISTINCT p.codInterno,
                CASE
                    WHEN f.idFabricante IS NULL THEN 99999999999999
                    ELSE f.idFabricante
                END AS fabri,
                '0', 
                p.descResumida, 
                p.descProduto,
                p.descProduto,
                p.codElemento,
                GETDATE(),
                GETDATE(),
                0,
                0  
    FROM    [192.168.200.87].[siac].[dbo].[IntPluProduto] p
        INNER JOIN  [192.168.200.98].[siac].[dbo].[IntControle] c on c.idProcesso = p.idProcesso
        LEFT JOIN [192.168.0.150].[tlmark].[dbo].[Produto] vanProduto on vanProduto.CdPrdSAP = p.codInterno
        LEFT JOIN tbFabricante f on f.idFabricante = CAST(vanProduto.CdFbr AS INT)
    WHERE  (select COUNT(*) from tbProduto where idSAP = p.codInterno) = 0
    AND vanProduto.cdFbr <> 'NNN0'
    AND CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    AND c.codModulo = 14
    AND vanProduto.ICMSubst <> 'T'
```

Comment: Já pensou em guardar no banco de dados a data/hora da última execução do JOB? Assim você poderia filtrar somente os processos que possuem data maior ou igual (>=) a data da última execução.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a query do JOB que está configurado para ser executado as 06:00 para filtrar a data atual - 1:

```
CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) > DATEADD(ss, 64800, DATEADD(d, -1, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS smalldatetime))) OR CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

O filtro acima não faz nada além de, partindo da data atual, subtrai 1 dia, e após adiciona 18 horas (64800 segundos).

Por exemplo, para a data atual 27/12/2016 06:00:00:

- Subtrai 1 dia: 26/12/2016 06:00:00
- Formata o resultado para: 26/12/2016 00:00:00
- Adiciona 64800 segundos (18hrs): 26/12/2016 18:00:00

Outra forma de fazer e que eu iria utilizar, seria a cada execução do JOB, atualizar uma tabela com a data/hora da última executação do JOB.

Por exemplo, criar uma tabela JobAtu, com um campo jobData (DATETIME). Quando executar o JOB, atualizar o campo data para a data/hora atual:

```
UPDATE JobAtu SET jobData = GETDATE()
```

Toda vez que o JOB for executado, ao invés de utilizar a cláusula:

```
CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

utilize:

```
CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) >= SELECT ISNULL(jobData, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) FROM JobAtu
```

Comment: AND CAST(c.dtHrProcesso AS DATE) > DATEADD(ss, 64800, DATEADD(d, -1, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS smalldatetime))) 
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Me ajuda neste problema de conversão, agradeço

Comment: Qual é o retorno da chamada CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103)?

Comment: O retorno é : 27/12/2016

Comment: E se fizer SELECT CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS smalldatetime)?

Comment: ai eu tenho o erro: The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Solução:  --teste, data anterior apartir das 18:00 horas 
 SELECT DATEADD(ss, 64800, DATEADD(d, -1, CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS smalldatetime)))

Comment: E.Thomas: A utilização de expressões usando tipos data (date, datetime etc) em T-SQL requer certo conhecimento e experiência. Novamente você posta uma sugestão errada para @itasouza, tanto que ele criou um terceiro tópico.

Comment: Por favor @JoséDiz. O tópico que ele criou novo é porque ele está utilizando outra `language` que não Brazilian. Pela tua resposta é possível ver que sua experiência se resume em copiar respostas alheias, editá-las e postá-las como suas. Minha sugestão não está errada para a `language` que estou utilizando. Realmente, acho que você precisa melhorar no quesito "conhecimento e experiência". Parei por aqui.

Comment: Agradeço a todos pela ajuda, Thomas, valeu cara!

Comment: @JoséDiz não vou dar palpites em [tag:sql-server] mas quando há opiniões diferentes o melhor é ter várias respostas para a comunidade votar e sinalizar o que foi útil.